# How to create custom "views" from multiple related lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation

I need to create a custom view from multiple related lists. List A has a drop down field that I would like to use the value to create a custom view. List B contains payments received for each of the items in List A monthly. I would like to create a view that displays List A Value 1 with all the related List B Values and then shows the total amount received of all the items in List B. To further complicate things List B spans multiple years and I need the user to be able to Select the Year and then the Drop Down Value in List A to generate the "Custom View"

Comment: Hi , your question not clear.. Would you like to create new form which should allow users to select a fields from list A & B? Please explain

Comment: Sorry, no I am trying to create a View/Report List A would be Accounts and List B is payments received on the accounts, these entries are by Month and Year. What I need is a way for the Site users to select the type of account and see all payments received by the year and with totals. List A contains multiple accounts that are the same type so we need to see how much money was earned based on Year and Type. Does this help?

Comment: Create a view -> apply Group by Account then Year-> to calcualte Total choose payment column SUM value under Total

Comment: The problem is the Account Type is in one list and the payments to be totaled are in another list.

Comment: In that case have to create a lookup column in main list. otherwise use Client side rendering method to create a view  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views

Answer (score 0):

To show data from multiple lists, you can use **Content Query webpart**. For reference:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-data-from-multiple-lists-with-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-d560f477-8fc1-4258-aeb2-70aa932e07da?CorrelationId=369f6118-03b3-4e5d-8d09-f1668944080f&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA010174134

Or you can create a **DataView** to show data from multiple list. For reference:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-data-from-multiple-sources-in-a-single-Data-View-f9898d20-a5ab-4973-9d16-9f4e4c088ae1

Comment: So these say SharePoint 2007 will this work with SharePoint Online Lists?